# ANTLR get all function args

Tags: python-3.x, antlr, antlr4

i have a function like below,

```
int foo(int i, int i2, int i3)
{
   return 0;
}
```

I used `visitDeclaration` to visit all the function declarations and then from there I came to `parameterdeclarationlist()` and I can see inside that there are multiple `parameterdeclaration` that has all i need.

I can get the first argument by something like,

```
...
    paramclaus = paramsqual.parameterdeclarationclause()
    if paramclaus is not None:
        paramdeclst = paramclaus.parameterdeclarationlist()
        paramdecltn = paramdeclst.parameterdeclaration()
        print(paramdecltn.getText())
```

but I cannot iterate over all the other parameterdeclaration objects.
I also implemented `visitParameterdeclarationlist` which gave me the function arguments, but then i dont know how the get the function name for those parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change:

```
parameterdeclarationlist
   : parameterdeclaration
   | parameterdeclarationlist ',' parameterdeclaration
   ;
```

into:

```
parameterdeclarationlist
   : parameterdeclaration (',' parameterdeclaration)*
   ;
```

you can do something like this:

```py
paramdeclst = paramclaus.parameterdeclarationlist()

for paramdecltn in paramdeclst.parameterdeclaration():
    print(paramdecltn.getText())
```